# JWT Token Creation In Java Using SAP Cloud Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, access-token, sap-cloud-platform

I am having trouble to generate JWT Access Token in Java SpringBoot Application using SAP Cloud SDK.

Below are the steps -

1. Created xsuaa service instance with plan apiaccess in SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit with service key.

   [image: xsuaa service instance]
2. The service key has clientid, clientsecret and url that will be used for generating access token.
3. Tried to generate the access token in Postman. It is successful as shown below.

   [image: Access token generation in Postman]
4. Switched to Java Application. The java app is a Spring-based project on SAP Cloud Platform.
5. Below is the java code for access token generation -

   ```
   import java.net.URI; import java.net.URISyntaxException;


   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   import com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.ClientCredentials;
   import com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.DefaultOAuth2TokenService;
   import com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.XsuaaDefaultEndpoints;
   import com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.TokenFlowException;
   import com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.XsuaaTokenFlows;

   import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

   @Slf4j
   @Service
   public class UserManagement {
       private String authURL = "https://{subdomain}.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com";
       private String clientID = "**";
       private String clientSecret = "***";


       public String generateJWTToken() {

           try {

               URI authUri = new URI(authURL);

               System.out.println(authURL);
               System.out.println(authUri);
               XsuaaTokenFlows tokenFlows = new XsuaaTokenFlows(new DefaultOAuth2TokenService(),
                       new XsuaaDefaultEndpoints(authUri.toString()), new ClientCredentials(clientID, clientSecret));

               System.out.println(tokenFlows.toString());

               String jwtToken = tokenFlows.clientCredentialsTokenFlow().execute().getAccessToken();

               return jwtToken;
           }catch (TokenFlowException e) {
               log.error("Token Flow Exception found ", e);
               throw new BusinessException(ExceptionEnum.TOKEN_FLOW_ERROR);
           } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
               log.error("URI Syntax Exception found ", e);
               throw new BusinessException(ExceptionEnum.URI_PARSE_ERROR);
           }

   }
   ```
6. I run the application in eclipse and below is the error:

   ```
    https://{subdomain}.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com
    https://{subdomain}.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.XsuaaTokenFlows@b3fea34
    2021-09-03 16:14:27.567 ERROR 15700 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
    c.b.s.a.service.imp.UserManagement       : Token Flow Exception found 

    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.TokenFlowException: Error
    requesting technical user token with grant_type 'client_credentials':
    Unexpected error retrieving JWT token:
    rb-app-lib-d.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com     at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.requestTechnicalUserToken(ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.java:187)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.execute(ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.java:139)
       at
    com.bosch.sbs.applibrary.service.imp.UserManagement.generateJWTToken(UserManagement.java:49)
       at
    com.bosch.sbs.applibrary.controller.UserController.testisds(UserController.java:69)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
       at
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
       at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)     at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)     at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$1(RequestAccessorFilter.java:75)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:317)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.lambda$decorateCallable$2(SecurityContextThreadContextDecorator.java:51)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:225)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:319)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:75)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
       at
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
       at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
       at
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
       at
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
       at
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
       at
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
       at
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
       at
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
       at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.OAuth2ServiceException: Unexpected
    error retrieving JWT token:
    rb-app-lib-d.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com     at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.DefaultOAuth2TokenService.executeRequest(DefaultOAuth2TokenService.java:82)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.DefaultOAuth2TokenService.requestAccessToken(DefaultOAuth2TokenService.java:59)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.AbstractOAuth2TokenService.getAndCacheToken(AbstractOAuth2TokenService.java:299)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.AbstractOAuth2TokenService.getOrRequestAccessToken(AbstractOAuth2TokenService.java:257)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.AbstractOAuth2TokenService.getOAuth2TokenResponse(AbstractOAuth2TokenService.java:246)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.client.AbstractOAuth2TokenService.retrieveAccessTokenViaClientCredentialsGrant(AbstractOAuth2TokenService.java:106)
       at
    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa.tokenflows.ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.requestTechnicalUserToken(ClientCredentialsTokenFlow.java:181)
       ... 99 common frames omitted
   ```

I want to first try to generate the access token locally in Eclipse. I am sure that the authentication url, clientid and clientsecret values are correct.

I dont understand why in Postman, I am able to generate the access token by using the url, clientid and clientsecret directly, whereas in java it fails.

Comment: This question is not related to the SAP Cloud SDK as you are using the XSUAA security library directly.
Can you please create a github issue directly on the security library's [repo](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration) to get their input?

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned process works fine if your application is not behind a proxy. I deployed this application to SAP Cloud and it works fine. The issue in local testing was proxy set by my Organisation. Hence I am closing this question. Thank you!